# Apex 21.2: anybody faced this type of problem and resolved?

Tags: oracle, modal-dialog, oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I created a page using editable IG where i have a dummy column of Type: Diaplay Only using it as a HTML Button to open a Modal Dialog (Master-Detail Form) which contains some data for DML operation.

I am passing a page item as parameter to Update that data. The problem is data inserted from a Single area when user enter an Order with its details (Apply Changes). From other side data should be completed by other responsible user as per requirement.

When user clicked on that IG row button sometimes it open Modal Dialog but some times showing error.

I can post screenshot here if its possible (don't know how to).

Error says in first line No Data Found but data is there i have checked data it seems ok for the rows opened dialog and for those not opening.

Is here anyone who faced this type of problem and resolved it? what can be cause to prevent to open it with data.

Error:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
Contact your application administrator. Details about this incident are available via debug id "384021".

Technical Info (only visible for developers)
is_internal_error: false
ora_sqlcode: 100
ora_sqlerrm: ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at 
"APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_FORM_REGION", line 2276 ORA-06512: at 
"APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_FORM_REGION", line 2238 ORA-06512: at 
"APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_FORM_REGION", line 2318 ORA-06512: at 
"APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", line 1246 ORA-06512: at 
"APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 3044
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_PROCESS
component.id: 54673220669894919
component.name: Initialize form Form on ORDERS
association_type: REGION
region_id: 117835482984053177
error_backtrace
```

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

> Initialize form Form on ORDERS

looks like a pre-rendering process which *failed*. It happens when primary key form item doesn't contain value (i.e. it isn't passed to the form). Therefore, check the way you're calling the form. That's probably what stands behind

> I am passing a page item as parameter to Update that data.

Also, enable debugging and - once you hit the error - check debug info. It might reveal some useful data. See page items' session state, because as if you *think* you're passing the value to the form, but - there's nothing there.

Comment: thanks @Littlefoot for your inputs, loaded data again after purging, created new page and now its working fine. regards

Comment: Thank you for letting us know; I'm glad you made it.